# pyinstaller program errors when i try to open it

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I ran the command `pyinstaller --onefile -w file.py`. It worked, so like any other person I instantly went to test it. But when I ran it it gave me a error saying `failed to execute script file` inside of a windows error message. I went to run the python script and it worked. I tried to run it with the console by running the command `pyinstaller --onefile file.py` and it gave me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the bundled application (not the script) from the console like `file.exe` on Windows or `./dist/file` on Ubuntu you will see the actual source of the issue in the console. This will help you to resolve it.

Comment: i tried that but it gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I used docker because It was build exe from mac os. see more https://hub.docker.com/r/cdrx/pyinstaller-windows

Comment: but isnt that just pyinstaller